# AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided when moving from a Test App to Production

Tags: azure, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-graph-api

I have two applications registered under the Azure Portal: a test version and a production version. My test App works fine with the Client Id and ClientSecret/AppKey that I got from the test app's detail from Azure Portal. However when I move to the production one as I replace the ClientId and Secret values with the one specified by the production App I registered, I suddenly get an error:

AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided

But I'm fairly sure that my client secret is correct as I just copied and pasted from the Portal. Is there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried simply regenerating the secret?

The error here is pretty straightforward and I do not think it is a fault with AAD.

Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: My problem was that my key from the Azure portal had expired.  Generating a new one with a new expiration date fixed it.

Comment: Not sure if this was implied here already, but I fixed this error by making a new secret key in `Azure Active Directory` for my client - not a key in Azure Key Vault, which threw me off.  Azure Portal > Active Directory > App Registrations > (your app) > Settings > Keys.  My key here was expired.

Answer (score 37):

Encode your secret ( e.g. replace `+` by  `%2B` , `=`  by `%3D` etc)

Comment: Thank you! My web app stopped working, even though the secret would be still valid for years. An extra `urlencode()` did the job for the PHP library being used (https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP).

Comment: What about the space before and after + and =? Do we have to use %?

Comment: I just ran into this problem: It's perhaps worth emphasizing that the client_secret needs to be urlencoded/%- even if it's been sent as part of an HTTP Basic auth header where the whole thing will be base64-encoded anyway.

Comment: Yup looks like this is a URL encoding issue. I kept regenerating my client secret until I got one with mostly basic upper and lower case characters. It would be nice to know the exact encoding Microsoft is looking for.

Comment: This saved the day! We were stuck in AzureDataFactory and replace helped.

Answer (score 10):

This may sound stupid but as it happened to me, it could happen to someone else (as clueless as me):
The code you need to use is not the one that says **"Secret ID"** but the one that says **"value"**.

Comment: Yeap that's my case, i am stupid :D

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Didn't happen to me but when another company sent us the app registration information I told my coworkers it was wrong and no one believed me (No one had tried using it yet and these were mostly non-tech people).  This helped me prove to them it was the wrong value. It shouldn't look like a GUID!! =]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the Expire time of the secret.
With 6,12,18 months there is no problem, I am using azure-cli 2.26.0
With 24 months you get the error:

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: fef57aee-deeb-47fa-ae05-ba8427cd4300\r\nCorrelation ID: ba3cc2d5-1594-4af3-be2b-3b35e8d40e06\r\nTimestamp: 2021-10-23 18:18:27Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2021-10-23 18:18:27Z","trace_id":"fef57aee-deeb-47fa-ae05-ba8427cd4300","correlation_id":"ba3cc2d5-1594-4af3-be2b-3b35e8d40e06","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had 2 keys. I created a third one, that didn't work. Finally I removed all keys and created a new one, but, just one. Then it worked.

Comment: this is the only thing (out of other answers) that worked in 2022, thanks

Comment: Same here. This is a Microsoft bug

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help some lost souls.

I had my secret setup in `secrets.json` at the beginning of the project, which I forgot. After the secret expired, I tried updating updated the `appsettings.json` to no avail, until I remembered and changed it in `secrets.json`. This was a test project run only locally. You could also have it in the `env` variables which also takes precedence over `appsettings`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been banging my head against this issue all weekend and this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when working on deploying a docker image to a virtual machine on Azure using Azure DevOps.

My initial Azure DevOps pipeline script was:

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy to VM
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy_to_VM
      displayName: Deploy to Virtual Machine
      steps:
        - task: AzureCLI@2
          displayName: Connect to Azure and deploy
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: $(AzureSubscription)
            scriptType: 'bash'
            scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
            inlineScript: 'az vm run-command invoke -g $(rGroup) -n $(vmName) --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "docker pull $(containerRegistry).azurecr.io/$(imageName):$(tag) && docker service update --replicas=1 --force --image $(containerRegistry).azurecr.io/$(imageName):$(tag) $(imageName)_app"'
```

**Here's how I fixed it:**

Adding the command `az acr login --name $(containerRegistry)` to the `az vm run-command` did the trick`

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy to VM
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy_to_VM
      displayName: Deploy to Virtual Machine
      steps:
        - task: AzureCLI@2
          displayName: Connect to Azure and deploy
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: $(AzureSubscription)
            scriptType: 'bash'
            scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
            inlineScript: 'az vm run-command invoke -g $(rGroup) -n $(vmName) --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "az acr login --name $(containerRegistry) && docker pull $(containerRegistry).azurecr.io/$(imageName):$(tag) && docker service update --replicas=1 --force --image $(containerRegistry).azurecr.io/$(imageName):$(tag) $(imageName)_app"'
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check you tenant Id and audience id from your config. You may still have a reference to the test environment.

Comment: The tenant Id is the same as I'm using the same directory. And I don't have an audience Id so I don't think that would be the problem either

Comment: If you can post your code or some screenshots, then it would be clearer to see what happened.