# encode variables with special characters for azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

Very Similar problem to [AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided when moving from a Test App to Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477266/aadsts50012-invalid-client-secret-is-provided-when-moving-from-a-test-app-to-pr)

The top answer says to Encode your secret e.g. replace + by %2B and = by %3D, etc how would I replace the special character Tilde ~

Comment: Which programming language/libraries are you using? There is a good chance that there is a library function that will URL encode the value for you.

Comment: @juunas Using python

Comment: Would this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9345102/1658906

Comment: @juunas  problem is got this key in azure DevOps library in a variable group so just storing the key and calling it in the pipeline.  want to keep it that way that's why liked the answer on StackOverflow which just  replaces a special character in the key directly  such as + by %2B  if there was something like that for ~ would be ideal

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case this reference should be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

- As Suggested by [juunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658906/juunas), and as per the document yes, you can replace the special character.

> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.

[image]

- Here is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for complete information regarding Encoding Techniques.